# How check one html element excist inside another html element using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want   to check   one html element exist inside another html element using jquery.Parent element have id 'preview' and child element have id 'draggable'.How check child element present inside parent element?

My code is

```
     if($("#preview").has("#draggable").length)
      {
          alert( "First element contain" );
      }
```

Any body give any solution for these issue?

Comment: as you are using `id` for child element then you can directly check `if($("#draggable").length > 0)` provided that `id` must be unique through out the html document.

Comment: I believe you yourself provided answer. Does it not working for you ? Show structure of both element than we will able to tell you

Comment: I want to check id 'draggable' present inside 'preview' or not?it is a draggable element.Some time it is inside preview or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `find()` function to find inner element `<selector>`

```
if($("#preview").find("#draggable").length){
    alert( "First element contain" );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
alert($("#preview #draggable").length) ;
```

This will give you non zero length if there is a `#draggable` is contained inside `#preview`.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#preview").has("#draggable")` it returns the boolean true or false.

```
if($("#preview").has("#draggable")){


}
```

Comment: @shkk No in first condition it is false it doesn't use

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming that you are looking to the immediate children of the `#preview` selector.

```
if($("#preview").children('#draggable').length > 0){
    console.log( "First element contain" );
} else {
    console.log('none');
}
```

If you have to traverse to the inner elements (e.g. possibility that `#draggable` is inside other elements), then proceed to @Affan 's asnwer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the if condition

```
 $('#preview').find('#foo').length
```

Thank You