# Check one html element exsist inside another html element using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to check one html element exist inside another html element using jquery.Parent element have id 'preview' and child element have id 'draggable'.How check child element present inside parent element?Any solution for these issue?

My code is

```
 if($("#preview").has("#draggable").length)
  {
      alert( "First element contain" );
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How check one html element excist inside another html element using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27519437/how-check-one-html-element-excist-inside-another-html-element-using-jquery)

Answer (score 4):

`.has()` selector returns boolean value. you don't need to find the length. you can simply use has selector to determine whether it contains element or not:

```
if($("#preview").has("#draggable"))
{
  alert( "First element contain" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.find()` and `.length` as shown :-

```
if($("#preview").find("#draggable").length){
   alert( "First element contain" );
}
```